# How to add recursively function

Tags: java, algorithm

I am confused how to write this in JAVA: There exists a staircase with N steps, and you can climb up either 1 or 2 steps at a time. Given N, write a function that returns the number of unique ways you can climb the staircase. The order of the steps matters.

For example, if N is 4, then there are 5 unique ways:

```
1, 1, 1, 1
2, 1, 1
1, 2, 1
1, 1, 2
2, 2
```

What if, instead of being able to climb 1 or 2 steps at a time, you could climb any number from a set of positive integers X? For example, if X = {1, 3, 5}, you could climb 1, 3, or 5 steps at a time.

Basically, I could do the first part and understand the logics with harder part with the set that the answer is: f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-3) + f(n-5). Can anyone help me? This is mine approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 int n = 4;
 Set < Integer > list = new HashSet < Integer > ();
 list.add(1);
 list.add(3);
 list.add(5);
 int ways = reachNFloorSet(list, n, 0);
 //     int ways = reachNFloor(n);
 System.out.println(n + " Floor is reached in " + ways + " different way/s.");
}


public static int reachNFloor(int n) { // easy part
 if (n <= 1) {
  return 1;
 }
 return reachNFloor(n - 1) + reachNFloor(n - 2);
}

public static int reachNFloorSet(Set < Integer > numbers, int n, int sum) {
 if (n < 0) {
  return 0;
 } else if (n == 0) {
  return 1;
 }

 for (Integer x: numbers) {
  if (x <= n) {
   sum += reachNFloorSet(numbers, n - x, sum);
  }
 }
 return sum;
}
```

I think that the problem is with the for loop, but I cannot figure how to make it correct.

Comment: I up-voted it because I think its not about the stacktrace or debugging it. He just needs to rephrase his question. He has a problem that he needs help with because he is unsure of how to design the algorithm to so as such.

Comment: Recursion is not a reasonable approach to solving this problem.  Your algorithm will be too slow and/or unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Since `reachNFloor` works fine without a `sum` parameter, why did you make `reachNFloorSet` take a `sum` parameter? Get rid of it to fix you problem.

Comment: @Mr00Anderson It's entirely about people doing their own diligence *(research)* before asking questions here. Debugging code is part of that, so the down-vote is appropriate, since tooltip of down-vote button says *"This question does not show any research effort"*.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - It seems to me that recursion is a completely reasonable approach. Of course you can get rid of recursive calls by using your own stack to record decisions, but that would hardly result in less complicated code. What else would you propose?

Comment: @Andreas: +1. No need to put sum as parameter as it has to be reinitialised each application of the function.

Comment: @TedHopp this is the Fibonacci sequence. the simple recursive solution has exponential complexity. Too slow. You can fix that with memorization. Too complicated and/or too much space. The simple iterative solution takes linear time and constant space. The matrix exponentiation solution takes log time and constant space

Comment: @MattTimmermans - The 1-or-2-step problem is the Fibonacci sequence, but OP is asking about implementing a general recurrence, of which f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-3) + f(n-5) is one special case. For any particular special case, it's easy to formulate it as matrix exponentiation, but how would you do it for the general case? Sure, it's possible to write a method to generate the correct matrix, compute the eigensystem, and solve, but is that really less complicated? Also, there's a lot of overhead before the asymptotic advantage kicks in, so for smaller n values, my guess is that it would be slower.

Comment: @MattTimmermans - Besides, this sounds like it might be an assignment where use of recursion isn't optional.

Comment: @TedHopp even for the general case, the recursive solution is unreasonable.  You're right that this is likely an assignment that specified recursion specifically, though -- which I why I thought it was necessary to mention that the recursive solution was unreasonable.  When the student becomes an engineer, you don't want him looking at problems like this and choosing recursive solutions that take exponential time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When `n` is negative or 0 in `reachNFloorSet()`, you're returning 0 or 1, but you should be returning `sum` or `sum + 1`. Otherwise you're throwing away all the accumulated info.

It would be better, I think, to rewrite your method so it doesn't have to worry about how many steps have already been taken:

```
public static int reachNFloorSet (Set<Integer> numbers, int n) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(Integer x: numbers) {

        if (x <= n) {

            sum += reachNFloorSet(numbers, n-x);

        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

You don't have to worry about `n` being negative, because you don't make recursive calls where that could happen. (Of course, you should guard against negative `n` in the original call as well.)